# Aspnet Core - Falha ao mostrar a data no formulário

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Estou fazendo um sistema para exercitar aspnet core.

No sistema tenho um cadastro de **Transação**, que já esta funcionando corretamente, e nesse momento estou fazendo um opção de editar uma transação que foi cadastrada no sistema, quando clico em editar, aparece um formulário com os dados antigos preenchidos, sendo um deles a **Data**, mas por algum motivo não consigo mostrar a data.

Já fiz algumas verificações, sendo elas:

-Quando clico em editar, o Id do item é passado pela url. Na model TransacaoModel o id_usuario_logado e o id do item, são passados corretamente.

-Cada variável que é adicionado no objeto item no metodo CarregarRegistro é adicionado corretamente.

Mas por algum motivo, quando chega na View as variaveis não pegam os valores, elas continuam em 0 ou vazias

segue meu código.
**View**

```
@model TransacaoModel

    <h3>Registrar Transação</h3>

    @{
        var vData = "";
        var vDescricao = "";
        var vTipo = "";
        var vValor = 0;
        var vId = 0;
        var vContaId = 0;
        var vPlanoContaId = 0;

        try
        {
            vId = int.Parse(ViewBag.Registro.Id.ToString());
            vData = DateTime.Parse(ViewBag.Registro.Data.ToString());
            vContaId = int.Parse(ViewBag.Registro.Conta_Id.ToString());
            vValor = double.Parse(ViewBag.Registro.Valor.ToString());
            vPlanoContaId = int.Parse(ViewBag.Registro.Plano_Contas_Id.ToString());
            vDescricao = ViewBag.Registro.Descricao.ToString();
            vTipo = ViewBag.Registro.Tipo.ToString();

        }
        catch
        {

        }
    }

    <form asp-controller="Transacao" asp-action="Registrar">
        <input type="hidden" asp-for="Id" value="@vId" />

        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Data:</label>
            <input type="date" class="form-control" asp-for="Data" value="@vData" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Data" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
```

**Controller**

```
[HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Registrar(int? id)
        {
            if (id != null)
            {
                TransacaoModel objTransacao = new TransacaoModel(HttpContextAccessor);
                ViewBag.Registro = objTransacao.CarregarRegistro(id);
            }
            ViewBag.ListaContas = new ContaModel(HttpContextAccessor).ListaConta();
            ViewBag.ListaPlanoContas = new PlanoContaModel(HttpContextAccessor).ListaPlanoConta();
            return View();
        }
```

**Model**

```
public TransacaoModel CarregarRegistro(int? id)
        {
            TransacaoModel item;

            string id_usuario_logado = HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Session.GetString("IdUsuarioLogado");
            string sql = "select t.Id, t.Data, t.Tipo, t.Valor, t.Descricao as historico , t.Conta_Id, c.Nome as conta, " +
                        " t.Plano_Contas_Id, p.Descricao as plano_conta from transacao as t inner join conta c " +
                        " on t.Conta_Id = c.Id inner join Plano_Contas as p " +
                        " on t.Plano_Contas_Id = p.Id " +
                        $" where t.Usuario_Id={id_usuario_logado} and t.Id='{id}'";
            DAL objDAL = new DAL();
            DataTable dt = objDAL.RetDataTable(sql);

            item = new TransacaoModel();
            item.Id = int.Parse(dt.Rows[0]["ID"].ToString());
            item.Data = DateTime.Parse(dt.Rows[0]["Data"].ToString()).ToString("dd/mm/yyyy");
            item.Descricao = dt.Rows[0]["historico"].ToString();
            item.Valor = double.Parse(dt.Rows[0]["Valor"].ToString());
            item.Conta_Id = int.Parse(dt.Rows[0]["Conta_Id"].ToString());
            item.NomeConta = dt.Rows[0]["conta"].ToString();
            item.Plano_Contas_Id = int.Parse(dt.Rows[0]["Plano_Contas_Id"].ToString());
            item.DescricaoPlanoConta = dt.Rows[0]["plano_conta"].ToString();
            item.Tipo = dt.Rows[0]["TIPO"].ToString();

            return item;
        }
```

Se esses dados forem insuficientes, é só avisar que compartilho mais.

Meu projeto esta [aqui](https://github.com/renanosoriorosa/MyFinance)

Answer (score 0):

Boa noite,

Coloca o seu código no GIT para que possamos ajudar com maior facilidade.

Uma coisa que eu percebi olhando o trecho de código que você postou é que na View possui um "Catch" vazio:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Remova esse try / catch e veja se não está ocorrendo um erro nessas linhas...

Att,

Edson José Martins

Comment: Eae Edson, desculpa a demora, fiz um repositório no github, postei o endereço na pergunta, vê se consegue me ajudar